# call click function method but not if it has another class associated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
 $('#commentContainer').delegate('div.comment-vote div.vote', 'click', function () {

//etc
}
```

I want this to get called but not when the div.vote also has a class "unauthenticated"

how can i do that?

```
<div class="vote"></div>//this one when clicked call click function in delegate

<div class="vote unauthenticated"></div>//this one do nothing.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`not-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```
$('#commentContainer').delegate('div.comment-vote div.vote:not(.unauthenticated)', 'click', function () {
```

Now the `click` event will trigger the handler only on `div.vote` elements that do *not* have the `unauthenticated` class.